# How to submit value of a Texarea from a HTML form and put it into another Textarea in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am facing this problem.

In my website, I have two pages. One is "**Trycode.php**" which has a Textarea in a form. The another page is "**Editor.php**" which also has a Textarea in a form. **I want to submit the Texarea value of "Trycode.php" and display it in the Textarea of "Editor.php".** Eventually the form in "Editor.php" is submitted to "ewsrc.php" for some reason.

Here is my code:

**Trycode.php**

```
<form id="tryit-form" method="post" action="/Editor.php">
<textarea name="codetaker" id="codetaker"></textarea>
</form>
```

**Editor.php**

```
<?php
$myCode = @$_REQUEST["codetaker"];
?>

<form id="edfrm" method="post" action="/ewsrc.php">
<textarea name="code" id="code"><?php echo $myCode ?></textarea>
</form>
```

**When I submit the form of "Trycode.php", the "Editor.php" page comes in the address bar but a 406 error occurs and nothing is displayed.**

What wrong I have done, say please.

Answer (score 1):

try change action of form (if both file in same dir)

```
action="/editor.php"
```

to

```
action="editor.php"
```

Also Try `$_POST` insted of `@$_REQUEST`
like

```
$myCode = $_POST["codetaker"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
<form id="edfrm" method="post" action="/ewsrc.php">
```

To

```
<form id="edfrm" method="post" action="Trycode.php">
```

And

```
$myCode = @$_REQUEST["codetaker"];
```

to

```
$myCode = $_POST["codetaker"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` instead of <strike>@$_REQUEST</strike>

```
<?php
$myCode = $_POST["codetaker"];
?>
<form id="edfrm" method="post" action="/ewsrc.php">
<textarea name="code" id="code"><?php echo $myCode ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to give full Base path in your action , the page you are looking for after submitting is some what browser is not catching it

```
<form id="tryit-form" method="post" action="your_base_url/editor.php"> // example
<textarea name="codetaker" id="codetaker"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the bellow cases and see..
1.if file name is Editor.php then action should be action="/Editor.php" not action="/editor.php"
2. try action without "/" use action="editor.php"